# How can I make Agricola vegetarian friendly?

Tags: house-rules, agricola

Agricola is a great game, with good theming, and I'd like to introduce it to a couple of friends who are vegetarian.

The problem is they might feel uncomfortable with the 'eating your animals' aspect of the game.

How can I change the game's narrative so that they're not eating their animals, but doing something else that converts the animals to food?

Comment: Is this really a concern? There are plenty of games out there where players are doing actions that someone would not normally feel comfortable with if they where really doing the action.

Comment: You don't have to convert animals to food in the game as it is. I've seen people do fairly well in Agricola with never even taking an animal. Sure, you may lose some points in the end, but you can make it up in other areas. You could explain to them the different paths to victory, and if they choose to avoid butchering animals for food, then bully.

Comment: A friend of mine is vegetarian, and we joked that the white cubes were tofu. I mean, they look more like tofu than sheep...

Comment: Farmers in the 17th century were eating animals. That's the game.

Comment: The usual advice when you're cooking for people and worried about dietary restrictions is *just ask them*. Your guesses will never be as good as what they can tell you. Surely the same applies here: don't assume your friends have a problem with games about farming and eating meat, just check with them. (I've played Agricola with vegetarians before and it never even occurred to any of us that this could be weird; seems premature to assume your friends will have a problem with it.)

Comment: I've a friend who is vegetarian who plays this.  He refuses to eat animals in the game.  Yet he has happy playing games with war aspects that will involving the fictional killing of thousands.  He never wins because he is deliberately putting himself at a disadvantage.  If they are genuinily uncomfortable about something pretend then i'd question if any game other that abstracts is suitable for them.

Comment: For what it's worth, my daughter has basically this same question, except for _Exploding Kittens_.

Answer (score 8):

The game already supports this with improvements like Pottery, which converts clay to food. Clearly, the imagined implication isn't that suddenly your family has a fulfilling case of pica — instead, the clay is used to make some good which can be exchanged for food (and this exchange is abstracted away in the game).

Imagine something similar for animals in the game, and there you go. (Of course, you'll still have to *part* with the animals — let's happily imagine that they are unharmed in that parting.)

Of course, if your friends follow the strain of veganism which holds that all animal agriculture is bad, this won't do, and you'll have to reskin the whole game significantly.

Comment: ...and avoid words like *reskin*.

Comment: Hey, vegetables have skin!

Comment: Haha, @TimLymington I lol'd at this :)